# How to revert changes from MongoDB when API call fails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, transactions

For e.g.

When an API gets called, some document was created but due to some issue with the server, it didn't acknowledge the response instead it failed during the process.

So how to revert the changes by removing the document from the database as the API call was not successful.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Are you asking about [multi-document transactions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/)?

Comment: MongoDB version 4.0x supports transaction API. Please check the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) If you are using mongoose from your app, you can check the official mongoose documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html)